# App missing from itunes connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, mobile-application

I created an app on itunes connect, and created all the provision profiles for it.

The next day, when I logged into the developer account, it said i had no apps ? 
And I have to create things all over again? 
How do I get to the details of my app?

Comment: Could it have failed to save due to some missing mandatory information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iTunes Connect is not where you create provisioning profiles.

Provisioning profiles are created in the Apple developer portal in the iOS Dev Center.

iTunes connect is then where you create actual apps for upload to the App Store. When you first create the app there are a LOT of mandatory fields. Even things like the icons and screenshots of the app are mandatory. If you haven't completed these then the app will not be created no matter how many times you press save.

I imagine that something was probably missing from the information and so it wouldn't let you save the app.

However, if the app was created then you will have received an email telling you that the app was created. Did you get an email?

Comment: no i did not get the email, but indeed you are right, i checked the portal, and all the info i entered yesterday is there, thank you